# How long should "searching for windows installations" take?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, repair

The computer booted today and sat forever on the Starting Windows screen. Finally put in the Windows 7 Home Premium install disk and chose the repair option.

It listed the Win7 OS, which I chose, but now it's been over 40 minutes with the pop-up "searching for windows installations".

How long should I be waiting for this to conclude? BTW, the system is multi-boot with Ubuntu and has been successfully running for years. Would it be worth it to boot into Ubuntu? Can I fix anything from there?

Comment: Impossible to say but windows does not simply stop working without a reason

Comment: After more than an hour of "searching for windows installations" I rebooted. Was able to boot to Ubuntu. Rebooted again just to see if Win7 would work. Now it's stuck at the "Starting Windows" flag logo. Gonna be a fun night...